# How to systematically remove and re-factor unused C# code?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have copied an older open source project (C# 2.0-ish, VS2010).
It does what I need, but it is not great and there is too much junk code.
I think only 20% of it is being used. I would like to remove everything that I do not need, before I can start to re-factor. Are there any tools that can help me do this?

Answer (score 4):

Resharper is your best friend.
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Get the trial version.

Comment: Just as well buy it outright; after using it, you won't be able to code without it.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if there is anything else like it. By the way, what is the appropriate menu in the re#er?

Comment: There are many other tools:http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/08/05/refactoring-tools-which-one.aspx. In resharper, it will colorize your code and marked the unused with hints and grey color.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the refactoring tools suggestions, there are 2 other things that you need.

1./ Source control (so you can roll back if you need to)
2./ Whiteboard (or some other place to nut out a high level design)

Answer (score 0):

NCover will help you find all the unused code assuming you have unit tests.

Comment: No, no unit tests. Would NCover show me everything that is not covered by tests?

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: Yes it will.